# objective-c iphone programming : set placemark custom name

Tags: iphone, gps, mkannotation

i just want to change the placemark name.
I heard i need to create a custom class but it doesn't work.

Always tell me the coordinates are in ReadOnly?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class that implements the [MKAnnotation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol. Your implementation can implement the title and subtitle properties. You instantiate your annotation implementation and add it to your [MKMapView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) via [addAnnotation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/addAnnotation%3a).